# PHP Extract Numbers Before Matching Text

Tags: php, regex, strpos

So I'm a bit stuck, I have a string like this:

```
$match = '**Mazon**'

$string = 'There are stores attached: Store1 (Detached) **28876.Mazon** (Detached) 28455.Targo (Detached) 28389.Walmo (Detached)'
```

output: **28876**

This gives me  **28876** but when i replace it with match = "**Walmo**" it completely changes.

Need to first match **Mazon** then extract the number before the period.

Code i got so far LOL i dont know much about PHP but im trying...

```
$data = strstr($string,".Mazon",true);
  
$output = substr($data, strpos($data, ")") +1);    

echo "<h1>" .$output ."</h1>";
```

Comment: It should return a value only when **Mazon** is used?

Answer (score 4):

To match the digits before all 3 words followed by a dot:

```
\b(\d+)\.(?:Mazon|Targo|Walmo)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent being part of a longer word
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match or more digits
- `\.(?:Mazon|Targo|Walmo)` Match `.` and one of the alternatives
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMg4oP/1) or a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/1Ftms).

Or a bit more broader variant to match an uppercase char after the dot

```
\b(\d+)\.[A-Z]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/By9G6X/1)

Example code getting the values of capture group 1:

```
$re = '/\b(\d+)\.[A-Z]/';
$str = 'There are stores attached: Store1 (Detached) **28876.Mazon** (Detached) 28455.Targo (Detached) 28389.Walmo (Detached)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 28876
    [1] => 28455
    [2] => 28389
)
```

Comment: ok let me try these out and learn whats going on thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could Regex for this. See these two examples:

To extract the value for Mazon:

```
$str = 'There are stores attached: Store1 (Detached) **28876.Mazon** (Detached) 28455.Targo (Detached) 28389.Walmo (Detached)';

$regexMazon = '/([0-9]*?)\.Mazon/';
preg_match($regexMazon, $str, $matches);

// Check if matches are found, the group is stored in $matches[1]
if (count($matches) > 1) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);  
}
```

The output will be: `string(5) "28876"`

If you want to get the value of Targo you can replace Mazon in the regex:

```
$regexTargo = '/([0-9]*?)\.Targo/';
preg_match($regexTargo, $str, $matches);

// Check if matches are found, the group is stored in $matches[1]
if (count($matches) > 1) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);  
}
```

The output: `string(5) "28455"`